# Slack integration for groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui, slack-api

I am doing API automation in `SoapUI`. I have test suit which runs and provides the report of the pass and fail test cases.

I want to add this result to the `slack` post. When my test suit will be executed completely, a slack post should be added with test case result. Wheather it's pass or fails?

Which library do I need to import in the Groovy script for slack integration?

Thanks!

Comment: if you are in soapui, then you can send message to slack using [web api](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage). in groovy you can use any http client library.

Comment: @daggett Can you share some code snippet? It would be helpful to me. Thanks.

Comment: Basically you need to use the rest service of slack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did that using URL class

```
def post = new URL('url')

String body="token=yourtoken&channel=yourchannel&text=yourtext";

def connection = post.openConnection()

connection.with 

{

doOutput = true

 requestMethod = 'POST'
  outputStream.withWriter { writer ->
    writer << body
  }

log.info content.text

}
```